# Re-apply filter to ListDataProvider (for a Grid widget) in Vaadin Flow 14

Tags: java, gridview, filter, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) 14 web app, I have a [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) widget on my layout, backed by a [`ListDataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html).

It seems that when I call [`ListDataProvider::setFilter`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html#setFilter-com.vaadin.flow.function.SerializablePredicate-), the filtering takes effect immediately. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

```
listDataProvider.setFilterByValue(
        Product :: getLegacy ,      // Boolean property on my pojo `Product`. 
        this.legacy.getValue()      // `this.legacy` is a Vaadin `Checkbox` widget. The `getValue` method returns a `Boolean` (presumably). 
);
```

My filter is based on the state of a [`Checkbox`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/component/checkbox/Checkbox.html) widget. When the user checks or unchecks that widget, I want the filtering to kick in, with more or less items appearing in the `Grid` widget.

I imagine I need to add a listener to the `Checkbox` widget. I suppose that should be a call to either [`addValueChangeListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/component/AbstractField.html#addValueChangeListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.HasValue.ValueChangeListener-) or [`addClickListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/component/ClickNotifier.html#addClickListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-). Or maybe [`addCheckedChangeListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/component/checkbox/GeneratedVaadinCheckbox.html#addCheckedChangeListener-com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener-)?

➥ My Question is:
In that listener, what should I do to **make the filter get re-applied to the data provider**, and therefore change which items appear in my grid?

Should I just be calling [`clearFilters`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/InMemoryDataProvider.html#clearFilters--), followed by resetting the filter with a call to [`setFilter`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html#setFilter-com.vaadin.flow.function.SerializablePredicate-)? Seems like there should be a more direct way.

Calling [`ListDataProvider::refreshAll`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/AbstractDataProvider.html#refreshAll--) seems to have no effect. In my reading of the documentation, that method should be  called (a) when changing the *content* of the items already provided by the data-provider, or (b) when *re-populating* the group of items being provided by the data-provider. So `refreshAll` seems irrelevant to my goal. In my `Grid` widget, the `ListDataProvider` contents are fixed, unchanging. I simply want to show/hide the items within that grid by re-activating the filter.

Comment: From my experience you just have to set the filter again when your filter changes (e.g. in value change listener of checkbox). Good question, though.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich My filter is not actually changing. The value used for comparison within the filter, the checkbox, is changing. As the use checks and unchecks that checkbox, I need the filter to run again and reevaluate the list of items in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The problem in your code is that the line `this.legacy.getValue()` captured the value of the `Checkbox` widget at the moment you are defining this filter. The value to compare to was extracted from the component when the filter was set, and that value stays the same even if the component is updated. It's basically the same as if you'd split it up to two lines:

```
Boolean value = this.legacy.getValue();  // Captured once, not when user checks/unchecks the checkbox widget.
listDataProvider.setFilterByValue(Product::getLegacy, value);
```

## Solution

You need to capture the current state of the `Checkbox` widget at the moment when its value changes, when it has been checked or unchecked.

Something like this, where the listener resets a new filter using the widget's current value.

```
this.legacy.addValueChangeListener(
    event ->
    listDataProvider
    .setFilterByValue(
        Product::getLegacy , 
        event.getValue()
    )
;
```

You don't need to do [`clearFilters()`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/InMemoryDataProvider.html#clearFilters--) in between since all the `set` methods are clearing any existing filters. There are separate `add` methods that preserve existing filters.

Contrary to what you stated in your Question, the `refreshAll()` method does indeed cause the filter to be run again against all items in the provider. 
You can use `refreshAll()` to cause the filter to be evaluated again if the filter is defined in a way that reads the current value from the component every time it's invoked.

```
listDataProvider.setFilter(
    product ->
    product.getLegacy().equals( this.legacy.getValue() )
);
```

By using a lambda in that line above, the current state of the `legacy` checkbox widget is captured on-the-fly as the filter performs its comparisons through the items in the data provider.